# Ordered field in convex subset definition

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, convex-geometry

In the  [following wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Definitions)
we read that :

> Let $S$ be a vector space or an affine space over the real numbers, or, more generally, over some ordered field. This includes Euclidean spaces, which are affine spaces. A subset $C$ of $S$ is convex if, for all $x$ and $y$ in $C$, the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is included in $C$.

My question is why we need the field to be ordered in this definition? and does this mean that there is no  notion of convex subsets in complex vector spaces?

Comment: The order is used to define "line segment". The notion of convexity in complex vector spaces is the notion inherited from the underlying $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are in $C$ then the line segment between $x$ and $y$ is the set of $(1-t)x+ty$  for each $0\le t \le 1$, so where do we use order on the field here?

Comment: When we're writing "$0 \leq t \leq 1$", then we use the order of the field.

Comment: @DanielFischer is right -- most of the time folks are talking about an ordered field, and this is required for most of the results I've seen in convex analysis. However, if I recall, I think one generalization for complex Hilbert spaces is to replace $0\leq t\leq 1$ with $0\leq |c|\leq 1$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|\cdot|$ is the complex modulus. However, I'm not sure which results still hold with this generalized definition.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think i see my confusion:  $0\le t \le 1$ is an abuse of notation of $0_F\le t\le 1_F$ where $0_F$ is the zero element of the field $F$ and  $1_F$ is the multiplication identity of $F$, and so $0$ and $1$ in this abuse of notation are not necessarily the usual real numbers.

Comment: In a sense, they necessarily are. Every ordered field has characteristic $0$, thus contains (an isomorphic copy of) $\mathbb{Q}$ as its prime field, and hence in every ordered field, $0$ and $1$ are (modulo canonical identification) the rational numbers $0$ and $1$. The difference between various ordered fields is "what lies between $0$ and $1$?". There are a lot of options for that.

Answer (score 1):

The line segment connecting $x$ to $y$ is the set$$\{(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\mid0\leqslant\lambda\leqslant1\}.$$As you can see from this definition, you are supposed to have an order relation on your field of scalars.

If $V$ is a complex vector space and $C\subset V$, we say that $C$ is convex if it is convex when we see $V$ as a real vector space.